# 301 Redirect Problems internal page and external page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i need create simple 301 redirect using .htaccess. I have 2 problems :

1. i want to redirect old url to new url (internal webpage) such as :

from

```
myweb.com/articles_bla-bla-123.html
```

to

```
myweb.com/bestarticles_bla-bla-123.html
```

So, every URL contain `articles_bla-bla-123.html` will be redirected to `bestarticles_bla-bla-123.html`

`bla-bla-123` is dynamic text because it is a title of article.

I already use below method but without success :

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

`RedirectMatch 301 ^articles_([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\.html) bestarticles_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\.html) [L]`

---

Any idea how to solve this problem?

2. Problem no.2 same like no.1 but different domain. For example :

from

```
http://www.myweb.com/articles_bla-bla-123.html
```

to

```
http://www.otherweb.com/bestarticles_bla-bla-123.html
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks so much for anyone who able to answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a simple RewriteRule:

`RewriteRule ^(articles_.+).html$ best$1`

This rule will prepend "best" to every html file request containing "articles_xxxxxxxx"

EDIT:

To change "articles" by another word do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(articles_)(.+\.html)$ readthis_$2
```

Comment: but how about "articles_xxxxxxxx" to "readthis_xxxxxxxx" ?? i mean i must replace "articles_xxxxxxxx" to "readthis_xxxxxxxx" so it is not about adding "best" as a word to become "bestarticles_xxxxxxxx"

Comment: @AlexReinhard Edited answer to reply